# Does Flash have a method that does the reverse of toString?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

When using ObjectUtil there is a method called, toString() that takes an object. If you pass it a class named, "Person" it will return the string "[class Person]".

```
var person:Person = new Person();
trace(ObjectUtil.toString(person));//UPDATE I'm not using ObjectUtil.toString()

// traces [class Person]
```

Is there a toObject() method? Something that takes the same format toString outputs and creates an instance like so:

```
var person:Person = ObjectUtil.toObject("[class Person]");
```

**UPDATE**:
Sorry. This is incorrect. I thought I was using ObjectUtil.toString(). I was not. When I use that method it returns something like:

```
(com.printui.assets.skins::fontList)#0
  accessibilityDescription = ""
  accessibilityEnabled = true
  accessibilityImplementation = (null)
```

In my code somewhere it is returning "[class Person]" like I was described. This is the line:

```
var currentValue:* = target[property];
popUpValueInput.text = currentValue;
```

I thought it was using instance.toString() but toString() is not returning anything close to that:

```
var f:fontList = new fontList();
var f1:fontList = new fontList();
trace("" + f);
trace("" + f1);
trace(f1.toString());
```

Results in:

```
fontList2
fontList5
fontList5
```

Comment: Well, there is [getDefinitionByName](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName()) which returns an Object of the specified class. In your case, `var person:Person = getDefinitionByName("Person")` if the name of the Class is ambiguous, you can also use the identifier like `getDefinitionByName("com.example.Person")`.

Comment: Hmm, what `ObjectUtils` do you use? Google says there is `mx.utils.ObjectUtil` (lacking "s") and `org.as3commons.lang.ObjectUtils` (this one lacks statis `toString()` method). The latter has a `toInstance()` method that makes an instance of a given class out of an `Object`, but not from a string. You should better look towards serialization process to store objects as strings/bytearrays.

Comment: Also, in your case your trace should be a `[object Person]` as you're feeding it an instance, not a cass description. Maybe post where did you get that `ObjectUtils`, its full class name and/or code.

Comment: I just realized something. I think I'm getting `"[class MySkin]"` from `myInput.text = mySkinInstance;`. That would mean I'm calling the Object.toString() method? This is a dynamic reflection class so I don't know what I'm going to get. Maybe I should use "[object " + getQualifiedClassName(mySkinInstance) + "]".

Comment: Nope, mySkinInstance is a class, myInput.text = wait for string, so flash/flex implicit call .toString() method from mySkinInstance to satisfy .text requerment. But you can override toString() method to return just the name without "[]". In general I;m sure that you do something wrong with this situation.

Comment: Yeah, I had some errors in my question. I thought that it was using toString() but if I trace toString() it is giving me different values. So I'm guessing the input.text is doing something?

Comment: OK I see it is coming from trace(fontList);. If I use trace(new fontList()); it is a different result. OK everyone else has said the same but it's too late for me to see it obviously. trace(Class) returns [class MyClass] while trace(myClassInstance) returns whatever is in the function toString(). The Class.toString() must be part of flash avm as you say?

Comment: yes any class has 4 default methods and one of them is toString. The default behavior of this method is to return the class name for classes In both cases trace implicitly call toString method to convert the passed object in to string. See my answer

Comment: After the update, i have no idea what your question is. Please explain again.

Comment: What is your goal eventually? Do you want to duplicate an object?

Comment: The question is if there is a way to go from var string = toString(object) to var object = toObject(string). I thought ObjectUtil was doing the toString but it is Flash Player AVM doing it. And it is different if it is a class versus an instance. I do not know how to get an instance to return class syntax "[class MyClass]"

Comment: I want to put a string representation into a text field and then convert it back again. So the text field may say, "[class mySkin]" from the component.skinClass property and if the user types, "[class myOtherSkin]" it converts that string back into an class.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts please ping me with @ so that I get a notification of your comment. You explain again what you are doing, which I already know. Please explain to me **why** you are doing this. What do you want to do with this information, why do you need it? Please provide a big picture overview of what's going on. Chances are there's a different way to deal with this, which is possibly better suited. You mention a reflection class in one of your comments, without any further explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should do this:
In your Person class add this method:

```
public function toString():String
{
    return "Person" ;
}
```

So to make an instance of the class by name use this code:

```
var p = new (getDefinitionByName(  ObjectUtils.toString(person)))
```

or it can be used a regex in general for all classes (thanks to 1.21 gigawatts ):

```
var p = new (getDefinitionByName( ObjectUtil.toString(Person).match(/\((.*)\)/)[1] ) );
```